# Why my sorting function works only in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a problem with my sorting function. Namely, my code works only in Firefox, but few months ago it was working on every browser. Do you have any solution for that? Every sorting function is similar, so I'm pasting only one of them:

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zfa6qkt5/13/

```
    handleSortNoteAsc = () => {
    let sortedAsc = this.state.data.sort(function(a, b) {return a.note > b.note});
    this.setState({
        data: sortedAsc
    })
};

handleSortNoteDesc = () => {
    let sortedDesc = this.state.data.sort(function(a, b) {return a.note < b.note});
    this.setState({
        data: sortedDesc
    })
};
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of linking to an external website.

Comment: I added example of one of the sorting functions.

Comment: It's similar, but it doesn't tell me why it was working 6 months ago

Comment: It may not have worked 6 months ago either, the size of your array will change the algorithm used by the browser and you may very well have different results on the same browser depending on the input.

Comment: Maybe you added some more code and this new code has some error which chrome detecs and does not run while it runs in firefox because it handles errors a bit differently. So maybe check your latest code since 6 months ago and see if this has any errors. Open chrome console and check for errors

Comment: Console showed no errors. Can it be related to chrome version?

Answer (score 0):

> Webkit requires the comparison function to return an integer rather
>   than a boolean, otherwise it does nothing with no error.

[Array.sort browser differences](https://allenpike.com/2009/arraysort-browser-differences)

Sort you array like this:

```
[3,1,4,2,5].sort(function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
});
```

Not like this:

```
[3,1,4,2,5].sort(function(a,b) {
    return a > b;
});
```

Comment: ...This quote... No, they do accept floats **and booleans**, as long as you use `false` to mean `0`, and `true` to mean `1` and anything that would evaluate to `<0` for `-1` you are fine.